# D3 - Make Axes Include Origin at (0,0)

Tags: d3.js

The following scatterplot example has origin at (2, 4) truncating the graph

even though range specifies zero.

.range([0, width]);
.range([height, 0]);

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118

Question ----> How to make origin start at (0,0) regardless of data

similar to the following example:

http://bl.ocks.org/hunzy/11110940

also with the same range

.range([0, width]);
.range([height, 0]);

Comment: You need to set the first *domain* value to be 0, not the first *range* value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Does this help?](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LJdZZ/2/)

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.y;
    })])
.nice();
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })])
.nice();
```